# Private functions inside lambda to create HashMap

Tags: java, lambda, private

I have an stream with following information :

```
X :{
   Y :{
       A :{ "key1" },
       B :{"value1"}
       C : {}
       ...
     }
}
```

Stream will contain a List of X Object's where X,Y,A,B and C is are of type Object.

I want to create a Map using Java 8 Lambda with values

```
        {
            key1:value1
        }
```

the key value pair should not present if the object C is not present.

I am trying with something like the below given code to get a List of keys but not able to create a Map of keys and values.

```
X.stream().map(p -> p.getAllYForX())
.filter(Optional::isPresent)
.map(Optional::get)
.filter(p -> checkifCExists(p))
.map(p -> p.getAllAForY(Y))
.filter(Optional::isPresent)
.map(Optional::get)
.map(p -> p.getKeys())
.filter(StringUtils:isNotBlank)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The functions definition is as follows:

*getAllYForX() returns Optional*

*checkIfCExists() returns a boolean if C exists in block*

*getAllAForY() is private function which returns Optional*

*getAllBForY() is private function which returns Optional*

*A.getKeys return String. eg: "key1"*

*B.getValue return String. eg: "value1"*

Comment: Did you look at `Collectors.toMap()` ?

Comment: Also: you say you want to create "hashmap with values" - what are keys?

Comment: Yes but i am unable to use it, Can you please help @Arkadiy

Comment: Keys are the String in A object and value are corresponding object in B

Comment: Please be fery clear as to what is a map and what is a list. Use JSON notation if you must.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Just want to emphasize that all the fields, Y, A, B and C are optional and not necessary that they will exist

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: So then would it be fair to say that your map is either always empty or contains a single key-value pair?

Comment: No, i just checked there will be mutiple instances of X and it can return more than one key-value pair

Comment: For the last time. please provide a representative input and output data using CORRECT JSON format for clarity

Comment: @Arkadiy Edited the question. There will be List<X> in stream. If the List size is 5 then there should be 5 key value pairs in Map. But if one of the X objects does not contain the object C then there should be 4 key value pairs in Map<String,String>. I hope this is helpful

Comment: not sure if doing that with (one) Lambda will increase readability...

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Can you suggest a cleaner and efficient solution. I can fetch two lists separately and form a Map but looking for something cleaner